# Copying animation keyframes from one bone to another with flipping

Tags: animation, bones, keyframes

### **Problem:**

I have two hand bones on a character that are meant to do the same animations, but on different sides of the character (left hand and right hand). This is on **Blender 2.92**.

I've gone ahead and animated from the side, before realising I've only animated one hand. I did not have the other bone rig selected, so the other hand missed out on getting the keyframes.

I would like to copy over the animation keyframes from the left hand over to the right hand, with little to no re-work needed.

### **What I've tried:**

I've tried to copy and paste the keyframes from the animated left hand to the non-animated right hand. It however, does not seem to work.

If the hands are holding something, the alternative would be to make the right hand a child of whatever the left hand is holding via a bone constraint. I'm not seeking to do this though, I would like to have the keyframes available for both for tweaking down the line without messy constraints logic.

Answer (score 2):

Figured out how to mirror the same animation keyframes to the other bone hand, without any re-work or manual labor required.

1. With the animated hand's bone rig selected, select all the keyframes in the Timeline (`Shift+F12` to get the Timeline view and use your mouse to box-select them all or press `Ctrl+A`) and copying them with `Ctrl+C`.

[image]

2. Then proceeded to select the other hand's bone rig (the non-animated one). With the non-animated bone, first setup at least one initial keyframe in the timeline. I did this with hitting `i` to put in an initial keyframe.
3. Lastly, the trick to get the animation pasted and flipped for this other hand bone is to have the Graph Editor open (`Shift+F6`) and right click in it and press **Paste_Flipped** (or alternatively press `Shift+Ctrl+V`).

[image]

Done! Now the other previously non-animated hand bone rig is now animated with the exact same keyframes as the other hand, just flipped so it looks correct!

This was all done whilst in **Pose Mode**.

Comment: Good one Yusuf!  :)

Comment: you can also do it in the Dope Sheet with a Ctrl Shift V